# colpitts oscillator with jFET not working

Tags: oscillator, jfet

I decided to build a colpitts oscillator using a jFET (2N3819): [image: jFET colpitts oscillator]

It seems to work fine @ http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ but when i try to build this circuit it does not work, any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What voltage do you see on the drain? Ditto on the grid? (er, gate)?

Answer (score 1):

Is transistor modeled in the simulator the 2N3819?

EDIT: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N3819.pdf

Sorry, for the not-too-insightful initial thoughts on your question.
By the looks of the data sheet above, the transistor you're using operates on much larger voltages than the one in the simulator.

Comment: I don't think so, no. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: edited my initial answer